# Dita-OT: markdown to HTML escape string / character (specifically brackets)

Tags: html, escaping, markdown, dita

Something's been puzzling me for the better half of a workday now: What's actually going on during markdown to HTML conversion in Dita when I try to keep brackets intact.

Specifically, this is my original markdown:

```
1. Value[:, :]
```

Which should be written as-is in HTML. However, looking at the HTML element produced by Dita:

```
<li class="li">
 <p class="p">
   Value
   <span class="xref"></span>
 </p>
</li>
```

Expected output:

```
<li class="li">
 <p class="p">
   Value[:, :]
 </p>
</li>
```

Which means the brackets are interpreted as an external references (?)

---

I produce my markdown to HTML conversion in dita CLI, version 3.1.2 (windows 10), with the following command:

```
dita --input=root.ditamap --output=./output --format=html5
```

The root.ditamap simply contains a single topic that is my markdown file.

---

**I tried at the following first:**

1) Using \ to escape the string, results in:
`1. Value\[:, :\]`

2) using html entity in-place of brackets (`&#91;` and  `&#93;`) results in: `1. Value:, :`

3) using UTF code in-place of brackets (`&#x005B;` and `&#x005D;`) results in:
`1. Value:, :`

**Then I tried to add more brackets there and it worked!**

4) Markdown that worked: `1. Value[[]:, :[]]` produced expected output `1. Value[:, :]`

---

**My question(s):**

1) Which of the three pieces is responsible for this behaviour: Markdown, Dita or HTML? (with this behaviour I mean the interpretation of brackets in a way that made them disappear during the original conversion).

2) Is there a "better"/"universal" way to escape strings in markdown -> html by dita? (By better way I mean something that will leave the original markdown's string meaning the same, and by universal I mean something that can be applied to all strings not only brackets)

At the very least I hope my findings will be useful to someone, even though I realize my use-case is very specific. :)

Comment: All code should be in code spans. Therefore, why not wrap it in backtics?

Comment: Very nice, that does the trick too!